# Qt requires C++11 support" make error

Tags: c++, qt, c++11

I tried Compile the latest tiled from source code following the instructions in README.md.

My working environment:

tiled source code: tiled-0.16.1

Mac OS: 10.11.1

Xcode : 7.1

QMake: 3.0

Qt: 5.7.0

Apple LLVM: 7.0.0

But the make failed with the following error:

```
In file included from pythonplugin.cpp:21:
In file included from ./pythonplugin.h:30:
In file included from ../../libtiled/logginginterface.h:33:
In file included from ../../libtiled/tiled_global.h:32:
In file included from /Users/Qt5.7.0/5.7/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qglobal.h:1145:
In file included from /Users/Qt5.7.0/5.7/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qatomic.h:46:
/Users/Qt5.7.0/5.7/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qbasicatomic.h:61:4: error: "Qt requires C++11 support"
#  error "Qt requires C++11 support"
   ^
/Users/Qt5.7.0/5.7/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qbasicatomic.h:90:13: error: unknown type name 'QAtomicOps'
    typedef QAtomicOps<T> Ops;
            ^
/Users/Qt5.7.0/5.7/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qbasicatomic.h:90:23: error: expected member name or ';' after declaration
      specifiers
    typedef QAtomicOps<T> Ops;
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
/Users/Qt5.7.0/5.7/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qbasicatomic.h:93:23: error: use of undeclared identifier 'QAtomicOpsSupport'
    Q_STATIC_ASSERT_X(QAtomicOpsSupport<sizeof(T)>::IsSupported, "template parameter is an integral of a size not supported on this platform");
                      ^
/Users/Qt5.7.0/5.7/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qglobal.h:746:66: note: expanded from macro 'Q_STATIC_ASSERT_X'
#define Q_STATIC_ASSERT_X(Condition, Message) static_assert(bool(Condition), Message)
                                                                 ^
In file included from pythonplugin.cpp:21:
In file included from ./pythonplugin.h:30:
In file included from ../../libtiled/logginginterface.h:33:
In file included from ../../libtiled/tiled_global.h:32:
In file included from /Users/Qt5.7.0/5.7/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qglobal.h:1145:
In file included from /Users/Qt5.7.0/5.7/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qatomic.h:46:
/Users/Qt5.7.0/5.7/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qbasicatomic.h:93:53: error: no member named 'IsSupported' in the global
      namespace
    Q_STATIC_ASSERT_X(QAtomicOpsSupport<sizeof(T)>::IsSupported, "template parameter is an integral of a size not supported on this platform");
                                                  ~~^
/Users/Qt5.7.0/5.7/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qglobal.h:746:66: note: expanded from macro 'Q_STATIC_ASSERT_X'
#define Q_STATIC_ASSERT_X(Condition, Message) static_assert(bool(Condition), Message)
                                                                 ^
In file included from pythonplugin.cpp:21:
In file included from ./pythonplugin.h:30:
In file included from ../../libtiled/logginginterface.h:33:
In file included from ../../libtiled/tiled_global.h:32:
In file included from /Users/Qt5.7.0/5.7/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qglobal.h:1145:
In file included from /Users/Qt5.7.0/5.7/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qatomic.h:46:
/Users/Qt5.7.0/5.7/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qbasicatomic.h:95:14: error: use of undeclared identifier 'Ops'
    typename Ops::Type _q_value;
             ^
/Users/Qt5.7.0/5.7/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qbasicatomic.h:95:19: error: expected a qualified name after 'typename'
    typename Ops::Type _q_value;
                  ^
/Users/Qt5.7.0/5.7/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qbasicatomic.h:95:23: error: expected ';' at end of declaration list
    typename Ops::Type _q_value;
                      ^
                      ;
/Users/Qt5.7.0/5.7/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qbasicatomic.h:99:44: error: use of undeclared identifier 'Ops'
    T load() const Q_DECL_NOTHROW { return Ops::load(_q_value); }
                                           ^
/Users/Qt5.7.0/5.7/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qbasicatomic.h:99:54: error: use of undeclared identifier '_q_value'
    T load() const Q_DECL_NOTHROW { return Ops::load(_q_value); }
                                                     ^
/Users/Qt5.7.0/5.7/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qbasicatomic.h:100:45: error: use of undeclared identifier 'Ops'
    void store(T newValue) Q_DECL_NOTHROW { Ops::store(_q_value, newValue); }
                                            ^
/Users/Qt5.7.0/5.7/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qbasicatomic.h:100:56: error: use of undeclared identifier '_q_value'
    void store(T newValue) Q_DECL_NOTHROW { Ops::store(_q_value, newValue); }
                                                       ^
/Users/Qt5.7.0/5.7/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qbasicatomic.h:102:51: error: use of undeclared identifier 'Ops'
    T loadAcquire() const Q_DECL_NOTHROW { return Ops::loadAcquire(_q_value); }
                                                  ^
/Users/Qt5.7.0/5.7/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qbasicatomic.h:102:68: error: use of undeclared identifier '_q_value'
    T loadAcquire() const Q_DECL_NOTHROW { return Ops::loadAcquire(_q_value); }
                                                                   ^
/Users/Qt5.7.0/5.7/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qbasicatomic.h:103:52: error: use of undeclared identifier 'Ops'
    void storeRelease(T newValue) Q_DECL_NOTHROW { Ops::storeRelease(_q_value, newValue); }
                                                   ^
/Users/Qt5.7.0/5.7/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qbasicatomic.h:103:70: error: use of undeclared identifier '_q_value'
    void storeRelease(T newValue) Q_DECL_NOTHROW { Ops::storeRelease(_q_value, newValue); }
                                                                     ^
/Users/Qt5.7.0/5.7/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qbasicatomic.h:107:86: error: use of undeclared identifier 'Ops'
    static Q_DECL_CONSTEXPR bool isReferenceCountingNative() Q_DECL_NOTHROW { return Ops::isReferenceCountingNative(); }
                                                                                     ^
/Users/Qt5.7.0/5.7/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qbasicatomic.h:107:34: error: no return statement in constexpr function
    static Q_DECL_CONSTEXPR bool isReferenceCountingNative() Q_DECL_NOTHROW { return Ops::isReferenceCountingNative(); }
                                 ^
/Users/Qt5.7.0/5.7/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qbasicatomic.h:108:88: error: use of undeclared identifier 'Ops'
    static Q_DECL_CONSTEXPR bool isReferenceCountingWaitFree() Q_DECL_NOTHROW { return Ops::isReferenceCountingWaitFree(); }
                                                                                       ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
make[3]: *** [pythonplugin.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [sub-python-make_first] Error 2
make[1]: *** [sub-plugins-make_first-ordered] Error 2
make: *** [sub-src-make_first-ordered] Error 2
```

After doing some research, I tried to add a line `CONFIG+= c++11` to the `tiled.pro` file and then make clean , qmake, make but still I am having the same error ......

tiled.pro :

```
# Check the Qt version. If QT_VERSION is not set, it is probably Qt 3.
isEmpty(QT_VERSION) {
    error("QT_VERSION not defined. Tiled does not work with Qt 3.")
}

include(tiled.pri)

!minQtVersion(5, 1, 0) {
    message("Cannot build Tiled with Qt version $${QT_VERSION}")
    error("Use at least Qt 5.1.0.")
}

TEMPLATE  = subdirs
CONFIG   += ordered
CONFIG   += c++11

SUBDIRS = src translations
```

Not sure what goes wrong here.

Any advice will be appreciated, thanks :)

UPDATE:

Tried

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11
```

and

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++0x
```

Still have the same error ......

I thought it might be in the C++ compile the `make` command use, here is some information :

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -c `python-config --cflags` -O2 -std=gnu++11 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.8 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wall -W -fPIC -DPYTHON_LIBRARY -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PLUGIN -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -I../../libtiled -I/Users/supersuraccoon/Qt5.7.0/5.7/clang_64/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Headers -I/Users/supersuraccoon/Qt5.7.0/5.7/clang_64/lib/QtGui.framework/Headers -I/Users/supersuraccoon/Qt5.7.0/5.7/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers -I. -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Headers -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AGL.framework/Headers -I/Users/supersuraccoon/Qt5.7.0/5.7/clang_64/mkspecs/macx-clang -F/Users/supersuraccoon/Qt5.7.0/5.7/clang_64/lib -o pythonplugin.o pythonplugin.cpp
```

Comment: Try also `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11`

Comment: Also try `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++0x`

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer tried both flag but still having the same error. Please check the update info of this question.

Comment: Have you tried to compile other projects? If not, you may need to open Xcode and accept its license agreement or run this in your terminal: `xcode-select --install`

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem building poppler with Qt wrappers and got the same error: "Qt requires C++11 support".

My setup is:

```
Mac OS: 10.11.5
Xcode : 7.3.1
QMake: 3.0
Qt: 5.7.0
Apple LLVM: 7.3.0
```

All I did was:

```
export CXXFLAGS=-std=c++11
./configure 
make
```

and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I know it has been a while.
How I finally solve this problem is adding in **CMakeLists.txt** the following line just after `project(MyProject)`:

```
add_compile_options(-std=c++11)
```

That says to cmake, to create a **Makefile** that will use c++11 solving issues.